# Modal Bootstrap - Always delete the last image and not the selected image i want

Tags: php, html, sql, bootstrap-4

In the site that I am developing, I want to delete the selected image, but it always deletes the last image and not the chosen image. Can someone solve this problem? Thank you!

All the code in this link

https://pastebin.com/tpQnMwfY

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
    <br>
    <div id="imagem_galeria"><a class="fancybox" href="upload/bairro_galeria/<?php echo $row['imagee']; ?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="upload/bairro_galeria/<?php echo $row['imagee']; ?>" class="image-responsive"></a></div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" align="right"><a href="admin_bairro_galeria_editar?update_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm custom-btn" >Editar</a></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" ><a href="#exampleModal2" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm custom-btn" data-toggle="modal">Eliminar</a>
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Pretende mesmo eliminar?</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning custom-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        <a href="?delete_id2=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger custom-btn" >Eliminar</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you inspected the a tag to see the rendered id value in the html? Also you may need to put your delete code here as well.

Comment: here you have all the code https://pastebin.com/tpQnMwfY

Comment: and the tag it shows on the html it is exampleModal2 and not the ID of sql

Comment: I'm not sure what is the reason. Can you echo the value of $_REQUEST['delete_id2'] in the delete script to see what is being passed

Comment: When you select the image in this case
https://imgur.com/twzGpvj
When you want to confirm delete the image only gets tha vlaue of the last ID of sql.
https://imgur.com/jYXfxsD

When i didn't have the Modal it did deleted without no problems

Comment: It looks like you are rendering the modalbox with the same id each time so when you click on the button to pull up the modal it's pulling up the last one rendered. try changing the exampleModal2 to exampleModal3, exampleModal4, etc...

Comment: I already changed to exampleModal but everytime i insert a new image or text it always delete the last one and not i did select

Comment: it only get the last value and not the value i did select

Comment: You are currently rendering the html for the modal, with the same element ID each time. Element ids should be unique. So each button should open a unique modal. Right now it seems like you have a bunch of modal popups rendered in your code all with the same HTML element id.

Comment: When you hover over the 3rd Eliminar button in this case imgur.com/twzGpvj, does it also say exampleModal2 ?

Comment: <a href="#exampleModal" ...>  and  id="exampleModal" ...  ... these should be rendered using php values based on the current iteration of the loop. Those values need to be unique.

Comment: Yes it says exampleModal2 the problem after you click in the first button "Eliminar" shows the PopUp and on the other "Eliminar" line in the image https://imgur.com/jYXfxsD shows always the last ID and not the ID selected.

Comment: I already change the a href="#exampleModal" ...> and id="exampleModal" to php but then don't show the modal....

Comment: What exactly did you change them to? Do they match with the first Eliminar buttons that open the popup?

Comment: it works now's i did it. i will show you waht i did...

Comment: <div class="col-sm-6" ><a href="#exampleModal2<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm custom-btn" data-toggle="modal">Eliminar</a>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

Comment: Ok glad to know it now works. Keep Codin'

Comment: Thanks for the help!